# Html.DropDownList - Html.GetEnumSelectList

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, enums, .net-6.0, html.dropdownlistfor

Setup in .net 4.8 mvc:
Model

```
public class FirstLevel
{
  public IEnumerable<SecondLevel> SecondLevelEntities {get;set;}
}

public class SecondLevel
{
  public AnEnumType EnumTypeSample {get;set;}
}

public enum AnEnumType
{
  noone = 0,
  [Display(Name="First one")]
  firstone = 1,
  [Display(Name="Second one")]
  secondone = 2
}

CSHTML

@model Sample.Models.Example.FirstLevel

@if(Model.SecondLevelEntities.Any())
{
 @foreach(var entity in Model.SecondLevelEntities)
 {
   @Html.DropDownList("xyz",EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(AnEnumType), entity.EnumTypeSample), new {@class=.... })
 } 
}
```

I am upgrading this to .net 6

```
@Html.DropDownList("xyz",Html.GetEnumSelectList<AnEnumType>(), new {@class=.... })
```

I am getting only noone in all my dropdownlist controls. I tried to add extension method and updated cshtml is below for this I got all the display value from enum and the value from entity is getting binded again so if one of the selected value is coming as First one it comes twice in the dropdown.

```
@Html.DropDownList("xyz",Html.GetEnumSelectList<AnEnumType>(), entity.EnumTypeSample.GetAttribute<DisplayAttribute>().Name, new {@class=.... })
```

EnumDropDownListFor is not available, I have even tried DropDownListFor but to no avail. I need to bind the display name in my dropdown and the right value should be binded by default only once.

Comment: What do you mean `I am getting only noone in all my dropdownlist controls.` ? I try `@Html.DropDownList("xyz",Html.GetEnumSelectList<AnEnumType>(), new {@class=.... })`  and this can render dropdown list with options successfully

Comment: But it is not binding the selected option it is just showing all values but I want the value that it was saved with on load

Comment: Do you mean when you submit the form, you want to bind the value of options in your model?

Comment: so I get multiple drop down with my logic... and all my dropdown list have the first value of enum noone binded in all my dropdowns is what I meant. There is preexisting data in DB and when I load the page it does not show the value coming in the entity which should be binded to dropdown.

Comment: Hi @Lucky, Please check the answer i updated. Hope it can solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get your point, Here is a simple demo with hard code, When the page load, dropdown list will show the options which binded in backend:

**controller**

```
 public IActionResult Hello()
        {
            FirstLevel first = new FirstLevel();
            List<SecondLevel> seconds = new List<SecondLevel>();
           seconds.Add(new SecondLevel()
           {
               EnumTypeSample = AnEnumType.secondone
           });
            seconds.Add(new SecondLevel()
            {
                EnumTypeSample = AnEnumType.firstone
            });
            seconds.Add(new SecondLevel()
            {
                EnumTypeSample = AnEnumType.firstone
            });
            first.SecondLevelEntities = seconds;


            return View(first);
        }
```

**view**

```
@model FirstLevel

@if (Model.SecondLevelEntities.Any())

{
    @foreach (var entity in Model.SecondLevelEntities)
    {
        <select asp-for="@entity.EnumTypeSample" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<AnEnumType>()">
            
        </select>
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are awesome Xinran Shen!!